# Is there any methods to stop this message on VScode(Suddenly Stop)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image]

I can't programming on my desktop (Window10) using vscode.

Almost... every 10~15 minutes vscode stop Run and the message "The window is no long responding" come and i have to Reopen my VScode.

How can i make my setting work well ??

Comment: Smells like some broken auto complete feature. Haven't used said IDE, but that's usually what causes them to lag out.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you're using mircosoft products.